# How to determine which child JPanel is selected inside a JPanel (java)

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I have a problem where I have several similar `JPanel`s, that are contained vertically in a main `JPanel`. My issue comes where I will have buttons that will only interact with the child `JPanel` that is currently selected (clicked on).

I have a controller that takes the main `JPanel`, how can I have a method that will return only the selected `JPanel`?

Comment: `JPanel`s aren't focusable...

Answer (score 1):

This is very difficult.  By default, `JPanel`s are not focusable (they can't receive keyboard focus).

You could try ascertain the current panel that contains the current focusable component by using `KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();` and using the resulting `Component`'s `getParent` method, but this is no guarantee, as the focused component may be contained in another container, contained within the container your interested in...

A better idea might be to have some kind of model that connected the buttons or actions to the child panels...?